# Downloading WorldPop Population Count rasters

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, tiff, netcdf

I am interested in downloading the 2020 UN Adjusted Population Count for Democratic Republic of the Congo at the 30 arc second resolution from WorldPop (See [here](https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=35845) ) as a GeoTIFF (.tif) file. I am trying to do this for multiple countries to I was exploring the [wpgpDownloadR](https://github.com/wpgp/wpgpDownloadR) package.

```
devtools::install_github("wpgp/wpgpDownloadR")
library(wpgpDownloadR)
wpgpListCountryDatasets(ISO3="COD")
```

Could I get some help with directly downloading the WorldPop Population Count .tif file for a specific country (for example, DRC, Nigeria, Belgium, France etc.)?

I have an R code for converting this GeoTIFF raster (.tif file) to a NetCDF (.nc file) if I already have the tif file locally pre-downloaded but if I want for a different country I have to download it and do this over again.

```
library(raster)

# Downloaded from above website
DRCWorldPop <- raster("cod_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated_UNadj.tif") 

rnc <- writeRaster(DRCWorldPop, filename ='DRC_0000.nc', format = "CDF",  varname = "Susceptible", varunit = "Persons", longname = "Susceptible", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I am trying to have a single generic code to use ftp to download the rasters for **any country**. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
library(raster)
library(wpgpDownloadR)

iso3 <- "RWA"
cov <- "ppp_2000"
path <- dirname(tempdir())

f <- file.path(path, tolower(paste0(iso3, "_", cov, ".tif")))
if (!file.exists(f)) {
    f <- wpgpGetCountryDataset(ISO3 = "RWA", covariate = "ppp_2000", destDir=path) 
}
r <- raster(f)
```

This allows you to loop over country and covariate. It also avoids downloading files that you already have.

Comment: Thank you Prof @Robert Hijmans, when using the wpgpGetCountryDataset function is there a way to access the list of all covariates? The "ppp_2000" option is downloading population data tif file as an extremely large file (at the 3 arc-second (~100m) resolution). I am however trying to download the 30-arc second (~1 km) resolution. If I replace the covariate with "ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated_UNadj" I am getting an error: 
  Entered Covariates: ppp_2020_1km_aggregated_unadj not present in WP. Please check name of the dataset

Comment: I believe this returns the list `wpgpListCountryDatasets(ISO3="COD")`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5961303/ash) when downloading the WorldPop rasters, I thought it might be helpful to point out that there is a bug in the `wpgpGetCountryDataset()` function. The function converts the '`covariate`' argument to lower case, and I think this results in it being unable to match the necessary dataset in subsequent calls to other internal functions, resulting in download failure.

This only applies to covariates that have both upper & lower text case (e.g. for covariates that include the string `UNadj`, it gets converted to `unadj`). This results in an error message, E.g.:

> `Entered Covariates: ppp_2020_1km_aggregated_unadj not present in WP`

As a temporary workaround, I succeeded in downloading the data by commenting away the line `covariate <- tolower(covariate)` within the function. Submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/wpgp/wpgpDownloadR/issues/8) on Github.